# How to get only the URL of nextpage (without <a> tag)

Tags: nextpage

Here is my Function

```
function next_pages( $args = '' ) {
    $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    extract( $r, EXTR_SKIP );
    global $page, $numpages, $multipage, $more, $pagenow;
    $output = '';
    if ( $multipage ) {
            if ( $more ) {
                $output .= $before;
                $i = $page + 1;
                if ( $i <= $numpages && $more ) {
                    $output .= _wp_link_page( $i );
                    $output .= $nextpagelink;
                }
                $output .= $after;
            }
    }
    if ( $echo )
    echo $output;
    return $output;
}
```

This includes the outer element, name etc, I want just the link e.g.

```
http://domain.com/article/2
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check out the source of [`_wp_link_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_wp_link_page/), you'll see all the URL calculations are coded directly within - you can either lift this code straight out into your own function, or sprinkle a little regex around the existing function:

```
function wpse_204737_get_post_page_url( $i ) {
    if ( preg_match( '/href="([^"]+)"/', _wp_link_page( $i ), $match ) )
        return $match[1];
}
```

Worth noting that `_wp_link_page` is a "private" function, and is not intended for use in 3rd party plugins & themes - it *may* be renamed/removed/deprecated in a subsequent release.

Comment: Awesome! It's working like a charm :)